# Multiple bash commands in background

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to execute multiple single line commands in the background from  php `exec()`. My script watermarks the video and deletes the original video and rename the watermarked video to the original name. I want to run the whole code in the background. I have tried both round () and curly {} braces but failed in the end below is my code which I am trying to run in background.

```
(/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' video_watermarked.mp4 && rm -rf video.mp4 && mv video_watermarked.mp4 video.mp4) &
```

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: What's the nature of how it fails to run in the background?

Comment: Check your paths. You use both `/video_watermarked.mp4` and `video_watermarked.mp4` (no leading slash)

Comment: @Eric i tested the command - it will appear to background but then stops when you try to use the shell. Running it with 'nohup' solves this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ffmpeg will automatically suspend if it doesn't have access to standard out.

You have two choices:
`nohup /usr/bin/ffmpeg ...` Will take care of the redirect for you, and place the output of ffmpeg in a file called nohup.out

Or add `2>&1>/dev/null` after the closing bracket in your argument to exec(). This will send both standard out and standard err to /dev/null.

Answer (score -1):

Your command seems fine. Maybe you don't like that background commands still output to console? In this case redirect output (notice **&>/dev/null** in the end of command):

```
(/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' /video_watermarked.mp4 && rm -rf video.mp4 && mv video_watermarked.mp4 video.mp4) &>/dev/null &
```

Or even better, you may force background commands to append their output to some log file:

```
(/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' /video_watermarked.mp4 && rm -rf video.mp4 && mv video_watermarked.mp4 video.mp4) &>>/home/$USER/watermarking.log &
```

Comment: FYI: `ffmpeg` *will* fail to run in the background if you do not redirect its output. From the shell it will suspend until you put in the foreground again.